# How do I name an underscore filename in a preference override?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

I am trying to override a template file in another module using a preference:

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Mageplaza\QuickOrder\View\Frontend\Web\Template\Add_multiple" type="Mymodule\QuickOrder\View\Frontend\Web\Template\Add_multiple"/>
</config>
```

This is the real path: **Mageplaza\QuickOrder\view\frontend\web\template\add_multiple.html**

My module real path: **Mymodule\QuickOrder\view\frontend\web\template\add_multiple.html**

I am not sure if I should have: **Add_multiple or Add_Multiple or AddMultiple or Addmultiple**

I have tried all of them yet none of them work. Does anyone have any idea how to override this file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A preference doesn't work for templates, it is designed to override Magento 2 classes.

The simplest way is to override this template file in your custom theme, or alternatively modify the Block to use your own named template file.  Change this using layout files.